What is the term for when the power is written behind the base?
Some time ago I watched a video discussing the notation of a “backwards” exponent, where the power comes before the base (e.g. ³2). I was wondering:
a. What this term was called
b. How it works
Thanks

Did the video not include what it was called?

@WasuChanyasubkit It did, but I forgot the name of it, which is why I made the post

Why not just watch the video a second time then ?

@Peter can't find it, it was a really obscure video and I couldn't find anything online when I described the concept

This process is called tetration. To display ${^{x}n}$ we use {^{x}n}. Raising $n$ to the $n$th power $x$ times. It's not really useful since you will get really large numbers.

That said the usual notation is $a\uparrow \uparrow b$ based on Knuth's up-arrow notation.

It is the main purpose (but not the only one) to generate huge numbers. However , for reasonably small entries this concept IS useful , for example to study the convergence of the infinite power tower or , if we take the power tower modulo some number to determine the last digits of , say , Graham's number.

Perhaps there is no "usual notation", but only a variety of proposed notations.
